# How to open various files(image,video,txt) as pop-up on the current browser page instead of opening in separate page?

Tags: 7, javascript

I have seen on several sites, particularly news sites, If we click on video, the video does not open in the separate page, instead small window in the middle of the screen pops-up and video does play there itself and you can close that and behind that your current page is as it is. Same way when we click the image icon on the stackexchange text form to upload the image, small windows open of drag and drop appears.

Hence is there possible in drupal 7, for images, videos, pdf, txt files, word files etc. which opens on the same screen as pop-up in front of current screen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're describing is a modal window. There's a few modules out there for Drupal that create modal windows. The one that probably best fits your use case (media consumption) is [Colorbox](https://www.drupal.org/project/colorbox). Out of the box, it only handles images but there are a number of supporting modules that can handle other media files. See the Colorbox project page link for more information.

Comment: Hhmmm, yes, it can work perfectly for the images and videos(along with other modules) as it is describing in its features. I will more explore that to figure out what other it can do, but that module perfectly fits for images. I am also looking same thing for the text/pdf/word files, so user can open that over the current page itself, so no back and forth. This may not be possible. If you would have seen the administrative theme on drupal site(SEVEN theme) that does same thing to some extend, opens everything over the page, that kind of thing. Thanks for this module info.